# Limiting parts and total of numbers in a string (regex)

Tags: regex

I'm trying to use regex to find tax numbers with the formats:

- nnn-nnn-nnn | nn-nnn-nnn
- nnn nnn nnn | nn nnn nnn
- nnnnnnnnn | nnnnnnnn

EDIT: some samples are `062-225-505, 62-225-505, 062 225 505, 62 225 505, 062225502, 62225505`. The numbers should not be any longer than 9 numbers in total

So far I have ([0-9]{2,3}(\s|-|)+[0-9]{3,8}(\s|-|)+[0-9]{3,9})

This works, BUT it is also finding `050821862257111` which is too long for what I'm trying to find.  How do I limit the total string as well as each part being limited?

Thanks!

Comment: Please include actual sample data covering all different formats of tax IDs.

Comment: Thanks!  some samples are 062-225-505, 62-225-505, 062 225 505, 62 225 505, 062225502, 62225505. The numbers should not be any longer than 9 numbers in total

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `^\d{1,9}(?:(?:-| )\d{1,9})*$`

Explanation:

`^` - match beginning of a string

`\d{1,9}` - match between 1 and 9 digits

`(?:...)` - non-captuirng group

`-|` - alterantion: match  or `-`

`*` - match zero or more times

`$` - match end of a string

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/AnXD4H/1)

Answer (score 0):

With a small change to your regex, you can limit the length to eight or nine numbers, although this would still allow a mix and match of the delimiters:

```
([0-9]{2,3}[\s-]?[0-9]{3}[\s-]?[0-9]{3})
```

If the actual number of delimiters is not important, then you could just remove then, and then just check the length of the remaining numbers.

Answer (score 0):

```
^\d{2}\d?(?:-|\s)?\d{3}(?:-| )?\d{3}$
```

[demo at regex101](https://regex101.com/r/lxl0qC/2)

This regex will only match if the spaces and dashes are in the right place.

This will match: `062-225-505`

This will **not** match: `062-2255-05` or `062225--505`

Answer (score 0):

Found with a combination of all of your help!  :)

\s\d{2,3}\d?(-|\s)?\d{3}(\1)?\d{3}(?!\d)

Found 62-225-505, 62225505, 062 225 505, and did not find 060821067254101

Thanks all :)